# How to install JBoss Developer Studio on Windows

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-developer-studio

I am trying to install JBoss Developer Studio 9 on Windows using executable JAR file.

I have Java in my machine and set the `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables.

But while launching the jar, I am facing this error:

> Java virtual machine launcher couldn't find the main class program will exit

Could some one please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Please share your PATH and your JAVA_HOME path

Comment: Now I can be able to do this from cmd prompt. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You may post your own answer in order to help others or delete the question at all. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `devstudio-10.4.0.GA-installer-eap.jar` from [here](https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/devstudio/neon/10.4.0.GA.html). I tried that.

Comment: That one works rather well.  I also created a devapps folder for it to be installed into.  Then pointed to where my version of the jdk is located.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue was but for future reference the install docs / guides for Developer Studio 9.1 are located here:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Developer_Studio/9.1/html-single/Install_Red_Hat_JBoss_Developer_Studio/index.html#Install_JBoss_Developer_Studio_Stand-alone_and_JBoss_EAP

Instructions may be written for linux users, but the same instructions apply on Windows or OSX once you're in a console.

Note that Java 8 is required for Developer Studio 9 and 10, so if that's not your default JDK (eg., JDK 7 is your default, or is found in your PATH before the entry for JDK 8), the installer likely won't work.

Perhaps that's the problem that was reported here?